# TSKILL not always terminating program in terminal service

Tags: vb6, terminal-services

Background: We have a VB6 application [1] that runs on terminal services. As part of the update scripts, `tskill` [2] is used to kill off any running apps so that the application may be updated. Sometimes `tskill` cannot kill the process, although remoting in, and using task manager can take care of it.

Questions: what could cause a VB6 mdiform app to hang and not get shut down? Is there anything we can add to the app to make it shut down more gracefully?

Notes:
1 - It was supposed to be replaced already, but the SAP replacement is more than 1 year behind schedule.
2 - The script command is basically `tskill theApp /server:theServer` as it iterates across all the servers.

Answer (score 1):

1. The app could actually have code to ignore the shutdown/kill request and cancel the unload.
2. I've seen where message boxes being open will cause an application to not respond to shutdown requests.
3. It's possible the main form is unloading, but there are other forms resident in memory that cause the EXE to continue running without a UI.